# Android GridView onscrolllistener - auto loading instead wait for scroll?

Tags: android, gridview

i am trying to implement onscrolllistener inside gridview, so when users scroll to the end of page, it loads more items. But i have a problem it is loading but - automatically in a infinite loop , and not actually waiting for user to scroll? Here is the piece of code I am using, this is the function for populating:

```
 public void populate(){

        gv=(GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView1);
        gv.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(this, list1,list2,list3));


        gv.setOnScrollListener(new EndlessScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLoadMore(int page, int totalItemsCount) {

                load(counter);

                // Triggered only when new data needs to be appended to the list
                // Add whatever code is needed to append new items to your AdapterView
          //      customLoadMoreDataFromApi(page);
                // or customLoadMoreDataFromApi(totalItemsCount);
                return true; // ONLY if more data is actually being loaded; false otherwise.
            }
        });


    }
```

Comment: and what is counter? at some point you need to return false

Comment: counter is number of items already loaded. load() is a function for loading items inside gridview. it is auto loading for some reason without waiting for scroll